# Birthday Box Django

Tags: django

How could I implement an Birthday Box in my django form.I'm been researching about Django AgeField and no result at the moment.
I'm using it for my registration page

An e.g is when you register for a site . You must input your birthday to verify your old enough.
How could I make an age field?

Comment: I don't think this is related to django. How do you want to verify user age? They can put any number in the field and the only option you have is to trust them. Unless you are requesting an openID or using OpenAuth. Then you may have some means to verify. But then you may not need to ask for their age explicitly. You may get it from OpenAuth.

Comment: Why would you want to store Age in the database, store their date of birth and compute the age. That way, you can keep track of increase in age

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [PositiveSmallIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield) is about as close as you're going to get from Django itself. As @dmitri said, there's nothing within Django that can verify a user's age. You could use the [SelectDateWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#selectdatewidget) to allow someone to easily enter their birthday, as it presents select inputs for month, day and year. It also allows you to specify a range of years, which would allow you to set a minimum year of birth.

Comment: I think you're missing the point, which is that although it's possible to store an integer for the age, unless you're leveraging OpenAuth, there's no way to *validate* the age.

Comment: Sorry , I mean a birthday box. When you sign up . I want to display a colomun that displays the month day year